# how to set subject to php contact form

Tags: php

```
$mail->WordWrap = 50;  // set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->IsHTML(true); // set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = $_POST['Visitor Details'];
$message = "Name :".$_POST['name'].
" \r\n <br>Email :".$_POST['email'].
" \r\n <br>Contact No. :".$_POST['mobile'].
" \r\n <br>Message :".$_POST['message'];
$mail->Body    = $message;
```

Comment: Give more explanation of the problem.

Comment: The ***less*** the good people know, the ***more time*** it takes to provide you with a solution and comments will just continue to grow until we know exactly which animal(s) were dealing with here. You may also lose people's interest in the question, depending how long they want to stick around. I myself, have a 5 mins. grace period for "no relevant code" questions. I know it may sound righteous, but I have better things to do than wait, as do others I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the field name like : field name is 'subject' , we can use subject according to below. `$mail->Subject  =  $_POST['subject'];` 
And if you want to add the fix subject: `$mail->Subject  = "Your subject";`

Comment: They are already using `$mail->Subject = $_POST['Visitor Details'];` - so my guess is that their form/elements are failing them. Plus, there isn't enough code in that question to support the problem they're having.